# FORMVIEW and GET

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to clean a FORMVIEW with very little success.  I have the following form:

FORMS...

```
class BookRequestNumberSearch(forms.Form):

q = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user')
    q = kwargs.pop('q', None)
    super(BookRequestNumberSearch, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['q'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'name2'

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(BookRequestNumberSearch, self).clean()
    request_number = cleaned_data.get('q')#
    if request_number:
        if Book.objects.filter(request_number__iexact=request_number).exists():
            try:
                Book.objects.get(request_number__iexact=request_number)
                self.add_error('request_number',' Error.')
            except Book.DoesNotExist:
                pass
    return cleaned_data
```

And the View....

```
class BookRequestNumberSearchView(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
    form_class = BookRequestNumberSearch
    template_name = 'Book/book_request_number_search.html'
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(BookRequestNumberSearchView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
    kwargs['q'] = self.request.GET.get("q")
    return kwargs

def get_initial(self):
    init = super(BookRequestNumberSearchView, self).get_initial()
    init.update({'q':self.request.GET.get("q")})
    return init
```

And the HTML

```
<form method="GET" autocomplete=off action="{% url 'Book:procedure_request_number_search_detail' %}" >

  <div>
    <h1 class="title">Book Request Number Search</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="section">
    {{ form.q }}
  </div>
```

This code works, but I can't figure out how to get Django to invoke CLEAN.  I suspect maybe because I'm doing a GET the CLEAN doesn't get recognized?  I've spent most of the afternoon playing with variations but no matter what I do CLEAN is just ignored.  Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that a FormView works is that it invokes the `form_valid()` method of the FormView once the valid data has been POSTed. So, you can add a form_valid method to your BookRequestNumberSearchView and in there you can access the cleaned data of the form as such:

```
class BookRequestNumberSearchView(LoginRequiredMixin,FormView):
    form_class = BookRequestNumberSearch
    template_name = 'Book/book_request_number_search.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return # should return an HttpResponse
```

Notice how I am accessing the cleaned data by doing `form.cleaned_data` (as per the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)).

I suspect, based on your code, that you might not be using the clean() method correctly. The clean method should simply process the data inputed into the form and transform the data into a "cleaner" state. You would then want to access the clean data and do your query based on that in the form_valid section.

Good luck!

You can see the FormView documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview).

Comment: Rohan Varma thanks for the feedback.  Is there a better way to go about validating user input via a GET method?  I'm new and learning.  I am in fact trying to "Clean" the data to make sure the query value exists before returning a 404 page.  Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: Hi Steve. I would recommend actually creating a separate search results web page with its own view. The url can be /results. Then when the user enters the query into the search bar it should redirect to the /results page with GET parameters like so. If the query is “hog”, the url it should redirect to /results?q=hog. Then the /results page view can handle the get method and retrieve the url parameters from the request by doing request.GET.get(“q”). Then in the view you can load the results page with the necessary results based on the query. I’d be happy to explain in more detail over chat.

Comment: Rohan Varma yes let's discuss in chat when you have time.  Thanks.